# Why is my ficus tree changing variegation color?

Tags: ficus, discoloration

I bought two ficus trees a little over a year ago, one with dark green/white leafs, and a smaller one with dark green/light green leafs. A while ago, the first one started growing leafs with the color pattern of the second ficus tree alongside other leafs with its original pattern.

[image]

It seems that the majority of new leaves now have the double green pattern, however some new leafs still have the green/white pattern. Both plants were bought in the same store and have almost exactly the same lighting conditions and stand about 2 m apart.

What's going on here? Do the lighting conditions favor the dark green/light green pattern?